# Prove S is a subring of R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let a be an element of ring R.  Let S = {x in R:ax=0}. Prove S is a subring of R.
First we will show that S is a subgroup of R under the addition of R.  We let x,y be arbitrary elements in R.  Then ax=0 and ay=0.  Subtracting the equations we have 
ax-ay=0 so a(x-y)=0 so x-y is in R. Right?
Now I want to show that xy is in R.  I know that if I could show that a(xy)=0 then I would be done.  I cannot seem to get there.

Comment: Actually, it's a right ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By associativity,
$$a(xy)=(ax)y=0\cdot y=0$$